# Nested numerical integration in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I have a nested integral where the limit of integration of the inner integral is the variable of integration of the outer integral, so it cannot be written as a double integral. The code is as follows:

```
T = spline(theta,[0; Y; 0]); 
Tpr = fnder(T,1);

z = @(x) ((1 - ppval(Tpr,x)).*((1+eta)/eta));
int2_aux = @(y) ppval(Tpr,y).*z(y);
int2 = @(x) integral(int2_aux,theta_min,x).*lognpdf(x,mu,sigma);
int2_val = integral(int2,theta_min,theta_max);
```

where theta and Y are vectors defined above in the code (theta by linspace between theta_min and theta_max and Y is the numerical solution of a fsolve routine), and eta, mu, sigma, theta_min, and theta_max are scalars.

For some reason, I cannot proceed like this. It shows me the error: Error using integral -- A and B must be floating-point scalars. I found on another website that a way of solving this is to use

```
int2_val = integral(int2,theta_min,theta_max,'ArrayValued',true);
```

However, when doing that the integral takes forever. Is there a way of doing this more efficiently?

Comment: Is is possible to [edit] your question to make your example a complete [mcve], such that we know a typical input and its expected output? Then we can more easily validate alternatives

Comment: Possibly this integral converges to inf.

Comment: I added some additional detail, hope this makes it an MRE. Let me know if it is not the case -- I'm new at stack overflow. Regarding the non-converging limit of the integral, it is unlikely that is the case because of the analytics of the problem and the finite support of the domain.